# ''A wait of x seconds is required'' returns by telethon( python library for telegram) how can I get rid of it?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

When I try to run code which is accessing my telegram account via an API, it runs fine until following error.

`A wait of 4013 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjNNh.png)

My code is following:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = xxxxxxx
api_hash = '468f15380793dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

with TelegramClient('sessionx', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
        channel='channelname'
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

Is there any solution, so I could get rid of it? What changes should I made into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Its limitation from telegram there are limitations on using `GetFullChannelRequest` if you exceed those limitaions you will face floodwait issues

Comment: not only this code(with getfullchannelrequest), but also I am getting same issue with other ways in accessing telegram account via an api. so can you send me link of docx or detail where i could know all limitations.

Comment: those are server side limitation afaik there are no documentation exists which explains of those limitations